# How to get total number of row entry that is grouped by rows on google sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, google-query-language

I have a table of data that is formatted like this

[image]

and i would like to extrapolate how many ASSIGNMENTS, PROJECT, and PERMITS total on all the engineers.

Im having problem because this does not really deal with numbers so no mathematical formula i cant think of will work.

Here is a [sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFHInOpzW_UubDE3T395x821yZeNFM1BUDa0E3FJZVA/edit?usp=sharing) of the image above.

Here is my idea of doing it but i have no idea how to code this into a formula on excel.

The formula will look for the key word, assignment, project, or permit and will then check if the next 2 column have contents in them if so then it is a plus 1, if the cell below the keyword(assignment,proect,or permit) is empty check if there is contents to 2 column beside the empty cell if empty then stop, if there is plus 1, if a plus 1 check again for an empty cell below that one rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(IF(B3:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(A3:A), IF(A3:A<>"", {ROW(A3:A), A3:A}), 2, 1)), "s$", ), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where not Col1 matches '^Enginee.+' and Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(IF(Sheet1!B3:B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(Sheet1!A3:A), IF(Sheet1!A3:A<>"", {ROW(Sheet1!A3:A), Sheet1!A3:A}), 2, 1)), "s$", ), "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 matches 'Assignement' and Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

Comment: Thank you for that, on the actual data there are more than just 3 results im looking, which part should i edit on the formula for that? Can it be done to look for only 1 of the result at a time and not all 3 at once?

Comment: It is possible to make matches 'Assignement' not case sensitive? Not really that important though :) just an idiot proof measure

Comment: @DrakeJest yes, use: `where lower(Col1) matches 'assignement'`

Comment: Great, thank you very much kind sir for the help !

Comment: Im trying to modify it to spit out only the number. currently it outputs the  Keyword + the total number, i would like only the number as that result would fit better on the table where the results will be place.

Comment: @DrakeJest change `select Col1,count(Col1)` to `select count(Col1)`

Comment: Thank you very much the completed formula with some error trapping is now `=IFNA(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(IF(JAN!$B3:$B="",, VLOOKUP(ROW(JAN!$A3:$A), IF(JAN!$A3:$A<>"", {ROW(JAN!$A3:$A), JAN!$A3:$A}), 2, 1)), "s$", ),CONCATENATE("select count(Col1) where lower(Col1) matches '", lower(H27), "' and Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))),0)`.